# Response template in api gateway not returning json in beautified format

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-api-gateway

i have added integration response template in api gateway  i.e the response from elastic search engine and i am trying to parse that response to remove additonal metata data like hits etc

```
#set($esOutput = $input.path('$.hits.hits'))
#set($orders = [])
#foreach( $esOrder in $esOutput )
 #set($order = $esOrder['_source'])
 #set($response = $orders.add($order) )
#end
$orders
```

the problem i am facing is the response which is being retured from the response template is in the following order :

[{user=kimchy, post_date=2009-11-15T14:12:12, message=trying out Elasticsearch}]

but i would want it in proper json format.What needs to be fixed here .

this is what i am getting from elastic search :

```
 {
  "took" : 1,
  "hits" : {
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "user" : "kimchy",
          "post_date" : "2009-11-15T14:12:12",
          "message" : "trying out Elasticsearch"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how i solved it  by writing VTL code in API gateway integration response mapping template :

```
#set($esOutput = $input.path('$.hits.hits'))
#set($one=1)
#set($length= $esOutput.size()-$one)
[
#foreach( $esOrder in $esOutput )
 #set( $order = "$.hits.hits["+$foreach.index+"]._source" )
 #set($dispatchOrder =$input.json($order))
 $dispatchOrder
  #if( $foreach.index<$length )
  ,
 #end
#end
]
```